# Custom styles in Apache Pivot TableView column

Tags: java, apache-pivot

I'm building a TableView using apache-pivot that will have some cells that will contain a currency value (or '-' if the value is null). For visual feedback I'd like the text to appear in green if the value is zero or positive, and in red if the value is negative. I'm not quite sure where to start with this - any pointers?

Many thanks,

Joseph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on the user mailing list for Pivot - the solution is to extend `TableViewCellRenderer` and apply the color style there depending on the cell's value.